# Процент элемента из массива

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Есть блокнот с большим количеством данных, например 1000 элементов. Данные - это пять разных элементов. Пусть это будут: а1, а2, а3, а4, а5. Они встречаются в разном порядке и с разной вероятностью. Каких-то элементов больше, а каких-то меньше. Я создал массив, заполнил его и перемешал.

Задача:

1. Выяснить какой процент каждого элемента встречается относительно всех элементов. Узнать количество и процент.
2. Как часто выбранный элемент, например а2, встречается через допустим через 3 других элементов. (а3, а1, а5, а2, а3, а5) тут через 3 элемента попался а2. Узнать количество и процент.
3. Как часто выбранный элемент, например а2, встречается подряд (а1, а2, а2, а2, а5, а3). Узнать количество и процент.
4. Выяснить, как часто встречаются выбранные элементы из связки (одно из или вместе подряд - всё равно) например а2 и а5, через 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 других элементов (а1, а1, а3, а2, а1, а5, а4) тут через 3 и через 1, но через 3 и 1 это две разные категории. Узнать количество и процент.
5. Выяснить, как часто выбранная связка элементов, например а2 и а5, встречается подряд (одно из или вместе подряд - всё равно). Узнать количество и процент.

4 и 5 пункты по сути это 2 и 3.
Всего 10 категорий.

Пример для 2 пункта:
У нас есть массив с числами. Всего 5 разных видов чисел, допустим, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 в разном количестве, допустим 1 - 50 штук, 2 - 40, 3 - 30, 4 - 20, 5 - 10. Они перемешаны между собой и встречаются в разном порядке. Задача - найти все числа 2, которые встречаются, после трёх чисел, не являющимися двойками. Например: 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 1, 2. Первую двойку брать не нужно, она идёт после одного числа. Вторую двойку тоже не берём она, после 4 чисел. А берём третью двойку, она идёт после трёх чисел, то, что нам нужно. А четвёртую двойку не берём, так как она тоже идёт после трёх ненужных чисел, но она не одна. Она идёт как пара двоек. А должна быть одна двойка.

По сути нужна двойка, которая встречается через 3 ненужных элемента, и всё равно парная она или нет дальше. Главное, через 3 ненужных, чтобы была двойка и вычислить, сколько таких ситуаций встречается в массиве.

Comment: Мне помогли на другом ресурсе, но я не понимаю этот код. `import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10)
arr[6] = 3
print(arr)
print(arr[3::] == arr[:-3:])`

Пытаюсь своим умом придумать алгоритм к этой задаче.

Comment: не могли бы вы нормально оформить код, который вы написали в данном комментарии, чтобы люди могли его прочитать и ответить вам)

Comment: Я немного изменил описание для второго пункта задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях вы приложили код. Он использует внешнею библиотеку NumPy, советую вам о ней почитать.

Использование этой библиотеки не обязательно.

Для начала разобъем массив на массив, содержащий xN-ые элементы, где N - это размер среза ( через сколько чисел нужно искать )

`array[N::N]` - наш массив, начинающийся с N+1 го элемента со срезом N.
После обработаем его в цикле, и для каждого совпадения с необходимым числом прибавим 1 к счетчику

```
N=10 ## Размер среза
D=a2 ## Число
counter = 0

for digit in array[N::N]:
    counter+=(digit == a2) ## Скобки для наглядности
```

После выполнения в counter окажется количество совпадений.

С ним вы можете без труда решить задачу.

Comment: Спасибо. я попробую.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, правильно код считает. Я поставил значения, чтобы код искал не повторяющиеся двойки, через каждый ненужный элемент. Но вроде не так работает.

`N=1  ## Размер среза
D=a2 ## Число
counter = 0

for digit in array[N::D]:
    counter+=(digit == a2) ## Скобки для наглядности

print(counter)`

Comment: Да, вроде работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем. Если ненужных элементов больше чем задано, то всё равно находит. Например найти а5, через 20 ненужных элементов, так он может найти через 25 элементов и засчитает, как решение. Это не то, что нужно. Но я ещё поработаю над кодом.

Comment: Решается добавлением STOP (20) в срез.

Comment: Находим а5 через 20 ненужных элементов в массиве.
Код:

Answer (score 0):

Йелекс, если я вас правильно понял, то вы хотите переделать ваш алгоритм для случайного числа входящих элементов? Если да, то вам стоит переделать ваши "громоздкие" вычисления:

```py
    a1Count = array.count(a1)  
    a2Count = array.count(a2)  
    a3Count = array.count(a3)  
    a4Count = array.count(a4)  
    a5Count = array.count(a5)
```

-стоит заменить простым циклом:

```py
l = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]#Num = 5
aCount = []
for i in range(Num):    # количество чисел
    b = array.count(l[i])
    aCount.append(b)
                 # и вот у вас есть список с ответами на 1 из вопросов
```

А в конце, если вам необходимо вывести каждое число на новой строке, то вот:

```py
for i in range(Num):
    print(aCount[i])
```

А если можно вывести все ответы на 1 строке, то:

```py
print(*aCount)
```

Аналогично делаете для все остального. Удачи)
***P.S.***

```py
array = [a1, a2, a5, a4, a1, a2, a1, a5]
c1 = 0

for i in range(len(array)):
    if array[i] == a2:
        if (i - 1) >= 0 and array[i - 1] != a2:        # я немого изменил ваш алгоритм так,
            if (i - 2) >= 0 and array[i - 2] != a2:    # чтоб он работал
                if (i - 3) >= 0 and array[i - 3] != a2:
                    if (i - 4) >= 0 and array[i - 4] == a2:
                        c1 += 1          # меня смущает только это
                                   # тут осталось только правильно считать 
                                   # нужную вам информацию

print(c1)
```

Comment: поясните причину, по которой стоит использовать цикл

Comment: @loverx Если у вас будет не 5 элементов: _a1, a2, a3, a4, a5_- а, например, 10, 20 или даже 50, то что вы будете делать со своими _по-строчными_ действиями? Вы будете путаться в своём же алгоритме, а так же это сделает ваш код менее читабельным. Да и в случае ошибки её легче исправить в _цикле_, чем n-ое количество раз исправлять её в _строках_. Так что, на мой взгляд, проще написать пару циклов, чем потом мучиться с **огромным** количеством строк.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы просто сделали начальный массив, который я написал вручную, циклом? Но меня интересовал больше всего второй пункт моей задачи.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю условие второго пункта, не могли бы вы добавить пример?

Comment: Конечно. У нас есть массив с числами. Всего 5 разных видов чисел, допустим, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 в разном количестве, допустим 1 - 50 штук, 2 - 40, 3 - 30, 4 - 20, 5 - 10. Они перемешаны между собой и встречаются в разном порядке. Задача - найти все числа 2, которые встречаются, после трёх чисел, не являющимися двойками. Например: 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 2, 2. Первую двойку брать не нужно, она идёт после одного числа. Вторую двойку тоже не берём она, после 4 чисел. А берём третью двойку, она идёт после трёх чисел, то, что нам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Почему сейчас не работает код? Вроде бы всё правильно написал. Вычел индексы с проверкой содержания нужного значения, но не работает.
Нужно найти количество элементов а2, если перед а2, стоят другие элементы до трёх штук, а перед ними обязательно другой элемент а2. Пример: ...а2, а1, а3, а5, а2...

```
import random

array = []

a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3
a4 = 4
a5 = 5

for i in range (50):
    array.append(a1)

for i in range (40):
    array.append(a2)

for i in range (30):
    array.append(a3)

for i in range (20):
    array.append(a4)

for i in range (10):
    array.append(a5)

random.shuffle(array)

print()
print(array)
print()

c1 = 0

for i in array:

    if array[i] == a2:
        if array[i - 1] != a2:
            if array[i - 2] != a2:
                if array[i - 3] != a2:
                    if array[i - 4] == a2:
                        c1 = c1 + 1 

print(c1)
```

Вот даже в буквальном виде не работает.
Он должен найти одну комбинацию, где а2, а перед ним 3 ненужных элемента, а перед ними снова а2. Но не находит. Значит ошибка в коде, но я её не вижу.

```
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3
a4 = 4
a5 = 5

array = [a1, a2, a5, a4, a1, a2, a1, a5]

c1 = 0

for i in array:

    if i == a2:
        if i - 1 != a2:
            if i - 2 != a2:
                if i - 3 != a2:
                    if i - 4 == a2:
                        c1 = c1 + 1

print(c1)
```

Comment: в вашем цикле в происходит интересная вещь:

Comment: Вы сначала сравниваете ваше число a2 c i, a потом с i-1, i-2, i-3, i-4. А вы должны сравнивать a2  с array[i]. То есть вы сравниваете а2 с числом i, а должны сравнивать его с числами array[i]

Comment: И что значит найти? Что в итоге надо вывести? Координаты первого/второго вхождения числа a2?

Comment: Нужно вот это. Только я не понимаю, почему выдаёт 3, а не 2. Как тут код нормально вставить?
```
import random
 
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3
a4 = 4
a5 = 5
 
array = [a3, a2, a3, a1, a5, a2, a5, a4, a1, a2, a1, a4]
 
c1 = 0
 
for i in range(len(array)):
    
    if array[i] == a2:
        if array[i - 1] != a2:
            if array[i - 2] != a2:
                if array[i - 3] != a2:
                    if array[i - 4] == a2:
                        c1 += 1           
 
print(c1)```

Comment: Цель: Найти а2, потом обязательно найти 3 элемента не являющимися а2, а  после них обязательно должен идти а2. И вести счётчик, сколько таких моментов в массиве находится.

Comment: Пожалуйста, свои решения и дополнения добавляйте в вопрос. Вы создали два "ответа" на свой же вопрос, хотя по сути ответами они не являются.

Comment: Я бы их не добавлял, если бы в комментариях можно было нормально код вставлять.

Comment: Вы можете править свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Цель: Найти а2, потом обязательно найти 3 элемента подряд не являющимися а2, а после них обязательно должен идти а2. И вести счётчик, сколько таких моментов в массиве находится.
Он находит 3 элемента, когда по коду их должно быть 2.

```
import random

a1 = 1
a2 = 2
a3 = 3
a4 = 4
a5 = 5

array = [a3, a2, a3, a1, a5, a2, a5, a4, a1, a2, a1, a4]

c1 = 0

for i in range(len(array)):

    if array[i] == a2:
        if array[i - 1] != a2:
            if array[i - 2] != a2:
                if array[i - 3] != a2:
                    if array[i - 4] == a2:
                        c1 += 1           

print(c1)
```